# Creating javascript charts using data on google drive

Tags: javascript, charts, spreadsheet

I want to plot charts from data in a google spreadsheet in my google drive. I want to then display the chart on my website using some javaScript charting library.
I've tried looking for a solution but I couldn't figure out. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

1) To get source data from google spreadsheets I'm using this function

```
function getWorksheetData(spreadsheetId, worksheetId, range) {
     return 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetId +
            '/gviz/tq?gid=' + worksheetId +
            '&range=' + range;
}
```

2) To draw a chart I'm using http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts